# Address of function not in any module?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a stack where one of the addresses is not in a module (or at least it can't be resolved to any module).   My basic question is where exactly does this code exist?  Is it a lump of code that has been generated in a newly created memory segment for example?

Callstack:

```
    ntdll.dll!00000000779914da()    
    kernel32.dll!0000000077741928() 
    kernel32.dll!00000000777755f1() 
    kernel32.dll!000000007778a7a2() 
    avcuf64.dll!000000007502a2f2()  
    avcuf64.dll!0000000074fdbd94()  
->  0000000075fd0be2()  
    kernel32.dll!0000000077757d54() 
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee58b1188()    
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee58b052c()    
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee57c348e()    
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee57c11f9()    
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee57c123d()    
    msvcr120d.dll!000007fee57c1259()    
    Performance.exe!main()
```

Modules:

```
Performance.exe 0000000001000000-0000000001034000       
ntdll.dll       0000000077940000-0000000077AE9000           
kernel32.dll    0000000077720000-000000007783F000           
KernelBase.dll  000007FEFDA00000-000007FEFDA6C000           
avcuf64.dll     0000000074FD0000-0000000075064000           
msvcr120d.dll   000007FEE57A0000-000007FEE59B1000
```

This callstack starts in main() and I'm calling 'getchar()' out of the C++ stdlib. Also avcuf64.dll is Bitdefender my virus software, so I presume that's some kind of key logger protection going on.

Thanks

Comment: It could be dynamically generated code, as you suggest, or it could be a bogus stack frame in your trace. Impossible to say without more context.

Comment: Agree, probably your antivirus tries some advanced tricks with generated code.